# Android getGlobalApplicationContext() when developing with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to develop an Android application with Kotlin, but a third party sdk that I am working with requires "GlobalApplication.getGlobalApplicationContext()" which doesn't seem to exist on the Kotlin version.

I converted instruction written in Java code to Kotlin code, but I couldn't find how to convert a line, which is - GlobalApplication.getGlobalApplicationContext()

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return GlobalApplication.getGlobalApplicationContext(); // This line
}
```

getApplicationContext seems to return a context object containing some data about the application, but I couldn't find a Kotlin version of it.
Any help will be very appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Just return the context which it required.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Comment: @Ashish Thanks for the reply, but I'm sorry, I'm a newbie to Android. Could you explain a little bit more for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return your application context.

For Java :

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return getApplicationContext();
}
```

For Kotlin :

```
override fun getApplicationContext() : Context {
    return applicationContext
}
```